# Insertion Sort functions doesn't list all the elements after sorting

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, insertion-sort

This is my insertion sort function :

```
Student *sort(Student* node) 
{ 
    if (node == NULL || !node->next)
        return node;
    Student *sorted = NULL; 
    while (node != NULL) 
    { 
        Student  *head = node; 
        Student **tail = &sorted; 

        node = node->next;

        while (!(*tail == NULL || head->id < (*tail)->id))
        { 
            tail = &(*tail)->next; 
        }
        head->next = *tail;
        *tail      = head;
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

So if this is supposed to sort 3.3, 3.1 and 3.8 , it sorts them such as :

3.3
3.8

I don't know what happens to the first element. If I give it a larger set of text to sort, it misses almost half of the text.

Been trying to figure out why it does this. I'm pretty sure it's the problem with my sorting function.

write function. This function is supposed to simply write the sorted result to a file :

```
 void write(Student* node) { 

  Student * curr = NULL; 
  curr = node;
  FILE *ptr = fopen("student_out.txt", "w");
  if (curr == NULL) 
    { 
      printf("Nothing to list. \n");
      exit(1);
    } 
  int i=0;
  while(curr !=NULL) { 
     fprintf(ptr,"%d, %s, %s, %s, %.2f\n", curr->id, curr->firstname,     curr->lastname, curr->major, curr->gpa);
      curr = curr -> next;   
 } 
return;
}
```

Comment: Note: inconsistent style . (and, less important, indentation)

Comment: Please show us all your code. You may think it is in the sort but it may very well be elsewhere (e.g. your traversal and/or print code). I tried it but it worked for the test cases I tried. But I had to make up the `Student` structure and the test cases as you did not provide those. If you still need help please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: after the second while-loop, you are losing the skipped part of head-next ... tail, with `head->next = *tail;` BTW: this is insertion-sort (crippled). The natural way to sort LL is merge-sort (which needs recursion in some way)

Comment: @wildplasser - merge sort for lists (or arrays) doesn't require recursion if bottom up merge algorithm is used. For lists, bottom up merge sort will be faster than top down merge sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working, the problem could be with the print out. Example code to test the case mentioned above, converted to be C89 compatible (since I'm using Visual Studio). I would have swapped the names head and node, but I left them as is to match the original example. I also changed the compare to stop when (*tail)->id > head->id (using <= in the compare instead of <) so that the original order of "equal" nodes is preserved.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Student_{
struct Student_ *next;
double id;
}Student;

Student *sort(Student* node) 
{ 
Student *sorted = NULL; 
Student **tail;
Student *head;
    if (node == NULL || !node->next)
        return node;
    while (node != NULL) 
    { 
        head = node; 
        node = node->next;
        tail = &sorted; 
        while (*tail != NULL && (*tail)->id <= head->id)
            tail = &(*tail)->next; 
        head->next = *tail;
        *tail      = head;
    }
    return sorted;
}

int main()
{
Student a[3] = {{&a[1],3.3},{&a[2],3.1},{NULL,3.8}};
Student *b;

    b = sort(a);
    while(b){
        printf("%3.1lf ", b->id);
        b = b->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tested the print function I have. It works when I don't use my sort function. So it prints out all the inputs. I changed the order of my sort function to match yours but it still doesn't give me all elements after sorting. I'll add my "write to file" function in the original post.

Comment: @tyrell_c - It would help to see the code that calls the sort function and then the write function.

Comment: I have it in the main. I call sort(node) and then call the write function the same way.

Comment: @tyrell_c - so  you have the equivalent of | write(sort(list)); | or | node * sorted = sort(list); | write(sorted); | ? You could start with my code, and then change one part at a time to match your code to see what the difference is.

Comment: I changed my write function to exact print functions with the while loop you have in your main and it still misses inputs. Very interesting. I may have problems not in sort but in how I read from file, how I store in structs, etc ... I may have to post all my code if I can't fix it.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was with the write function as you said. Thank you so much!